# tcp client connection in php

Tags: php, tcp, connection

I have a webservice which connects to a server and return result as xml or json. It is written in asp.net. I want to use the same in php.

```
using (TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient()) 
    { 
        tcpClient.Connect("1.1.1.1", port: 42011);
        string search = "search^10|5|2|1^gagl^55592a782ce899d2" + 
System.Environment.NewLine; 
        using (NetworkStream ns = tcpClient.GetStream()) 
        { 
            byte[] bytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(search); 
            ns.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length); 
            string result = ReadBuffer(ns); 

          // [.. consume result XML string ..] 

        } 
        tcpClient.Close(); 
    }
        }
protected string ReadBuffer(NetworkStream ns) 
{ 
    byte[] lenghtBuffer = new byte[4]; 
    int bytesRead = 0; 
    while (bytesRead < 4) 
        bytesRead += ns.Read(lenghtBuffer, bytesRead, 4 - bytesRead); 
    if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) 
        Array.Reverse(lenghtBuffer); 
    int responseLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(lenghtBuffer, 0); 
    byte[] buffer = new byte[responseLength]; 
    bytesRead = 0; 
    while (bytesRead < responseLength) 
        bytesRead += ns.Read(buffer, bytesRead, responseLength - bytesRead); 
    string result = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead); 
    return result; 
}
```

The above codes return values in .net. How to get the result in php using the same values.

Comment: <?php
$fp = fsockopen("1.1.1.1", 42011, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
   echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
   $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
   $out .= "Host: 1.1.1.1\r\n";
   $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
   fwrite($fp, $out);
   while (!feof($fp)) {
       echo fgets($fp, 128);
   }
   fclose($fp);
}
?> this didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You can use fsockopen (http://php.net/manual/fr/function.fsockopen.php) to open the TCP connection and retrieve the result.

Comment: I tried that. 
<?php $fp = fsockopen("1.1.1.1", 42011, $errno, $errstr, 30); if (!$fp) { echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n"; } else { $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"; $out .= "Host: 1.1.1.1\r\n"; $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; fwrite($fp, $out); while (!feof($fp)) { echo fgets($fp, 128); } fclose($fp); } ?> this didnt work

Comment: yes, I am able to connect to the ip through the port. I am getting response also -"403 unauthorized access". It is because the string "search^10|5|2|1^gagl^55592a782ce899d2" is not being passed properly. 55592a782ce899d2 this is a value which the server will validate.

Comment: @[403] Request Denied: You are not authorized to use this service